# How to save low quality image and high quality image in one JPG file?

Tags: html, image, image-processing, imagemagick

Many years ago (when the Internet was slow), I saw websites that showed JPG images while the browser downloading them.

I'm not speaking about two versions of images. The browser first downloads low-quality and then downloads the high-quality versions. I am speaking about one file such that while the browser downloads it, it shows the low quality version of the image (from the first bytes) until the image is ready.

Do you know how do it and what is the name of that technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [interlaced progressive JPEG format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps))

The idea is that the compression of the image is made in such away that the when you send the image the receiver gets the image in finer and finer detail has the sending of the data progressed.

Comment: Thanks Amitay :). I found this following your link https://nuwen.net/png.html
Do you know if Sketch and Photshop created this by default for PNG files?

Comment: Sorry i don't know.

Comment: Interesting question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449314/when-to-interlace-an-image). Also note that interlaced JPEG is not supported by some devices (Photoframes, some TVs...) despite being over 10 years old.